# How to convert a string to a particular date format in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, datetime

I am reading a csv into a dataframe and trying to format data from a date column. The value for that column is showing as:
"2/1/2021 0:00:00" as a class 'str'. I want to convert it to an actual datetime type formatted like this:

```
 date_obj1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(p_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

but I am getting an error saying `ValueError: time data '2/1/2021 0:00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'` What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: 2/1/2021 matches `'%d/%m/%Y'` or probably month/day/year

Comment: `date_obj1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(p_date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")`
in your case will be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any character not preceded by a `%` symbol in your format string means that it will be matched as-is. In your current format string, these characters are `-`, `T` and `:`. For instance, your current format string of `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S` successfully imports `2021-02-01T00:00:00` as a `datetime` object.

A format string that works with your specified data format is `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S`.

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for more information.